# Xamarin Scroll-View is supposed to jump to bottom

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I have a `ViewSwitcher` in which I have a `TextView` around which is a `ScrollView` to get a scrollbar. I need it to automatically scroll to the bottom. Is there some kind of property to do that? I already tried putting gravity on bottom.

Here's my code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />
    </ScrollView>
</ViewSwitcher>
```

Comment: could you provide the code of what you've done so far?

Comment: @Benjamin I provided code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in your AXML though. It seems to me that you have to do this in your code-behind. In the corresponding activity of the layout file, please put the following snippet in your `OnCreate` override:

```
var scrollView = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.SCROLLER_ID);
scrollView.Post(() =>
{
    scrollView.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down);
});
```

You might have to use [`Post()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) or [`PostDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)), play around with it. Also have a look at the [`fullScroll()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#fullScroll(int)) method in the docs.

An alternative way if above doesn't work, is calling [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int)) on the `ScrollView` like this:

```
var scrollView = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.SCROLLER_ID);
scrollView.Post(() =>
{
    scrollView.ScrollTo(0, scrollView.Bottom);
});
```